# Multiple WHERE conditions with one OR - Codeigniter

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I was wondering how to have the first condition constant and only the two bottom conditions as or in codeigniter. It seems to ignore the first condition when the or_where condition is there. How can I specify only the or to apply to the "where private"?

```
$this->db->where_in('user_id', $followers);

$this->db->where("private", "no");

$this->db->or_where("private", "yes");
```

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Unfortunately you can't do that using CodeIgniter's ActiveRecord functions. ActiveRecord doesn't have the capability for brackets around where statements as such.

You can manually write this like so:

```
$this->db->where('(`private` = "no" OR `private` = "yes")');
```

Comment: As someone who just used this a couple of minutes ago, this is true.

Answer (score 2):

I think this should do the trick:

```
$this->db->where("(private='no' OR private='yes' )");
```